# Flutter 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I have a Flutter app that I'm trying to run on iOS with a custom Xcode build configuration. I followed the steps outlined in the Flutter documentation and created a new flavor called "dev". When I run the app from Xcode with the "dev" configuration selected, everything works fine. However, when I try to run the app from the command line with the command flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart, I get the following error:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
/Users/nicrorea/Projects/myapp/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/Firebase.h:14:8

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'
/Users/nicrorea/Projects/myapp/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:1:7
```

I tried cleaning the Xcode build folder and running flutter clean before running the command again, but the error persists. I also checked that the FirebaseCore framework is included in the "dev" configuration's build settings. I was expecting the app to run without any errors since it builds and runs fine in Xcode. I also checked other stackoverflow solutions for this error but none worked

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can try:

1. Open Podfile -> Add `post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64" end end`
2. Remove Podfile -> `pod install`

I hope it can help you.